# Do I need to install SQL Express to use an MDB in App_Data

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-express

If i have a server with ASP.NET 3.5 installed, where no one explicitly installed SQL Express. Can my web application still connect to an MDF file in the App_Data folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you need SQL Express installed, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165716.aspx.

You could always deploy your DB to another server which has SQL Server installed though. Just have to also update connection string.

You can do this if you are using SQL CE 4 though, http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/30/new-embedded-database-support-with-asp-net.aspx